# How to turn an LED on in an inverter circuit

Tags: led, circuit-design, logic-gates, npn

I am currently trying to build an inverter circuit which turns on an LED (on a simulation before building it physically). I am using an 2N3904 NPN transistor, 5V voltage sources, a 220k and a 47k resistor as follows.
The potential difference vOut at the collector acts as usual. However, once I connect the LED there, the voltage drops to less than 1 and the LED does not light.

Someone told me to lower the resistances of the circuit? Is there any other way to achieve the goal without having to change the resistances?

This is the circuit so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fygSDw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The reason why the voltage drops is because current flows through R2 and D1, and D1 limits the vOut to it's forward voltage of 0.6 works. Perhaps lowering R2 could help, but it is a wrong way to build such a circuit and I doubt it would work, since D1 connected in parallel to Q1 (transistor in a way is just TWO diodes, therefore two diode drops) will affect it.

The right way to build such a inverting circuit is to add a second transistor.

Comment: I accidentally added the LED there, shortening the circuit. How would I connect the LED correctly?

Comment: @iAndrea Do you want the LED to be ON when VIN is not 0? Or oppositely so?

Comment: I would like the LED to be on when Vin is 0 (Vout is 5) and off when Vin is 5 (Vout is 0)

Comment: The issue here is that the LED needs a fair amount of power to be illuminated.  Approx. 5mA * 2V at a guess.  This is at odds with your open collector topology - which will draw minimal current through R2 when the transistor is OFF.  You could connect the diode from V1 (5V) to VIN through a 600 ohm resistor.  This would have the behavior you desire, and would not load down VOUT.  (current flows through LED + resistor when VIN = 0 and does not flow when VIN = 5V).

Comment: Troutdog could you please share the schematic for your idea if that is okay with you? I am trying to replicate your instructions but the current does not exceed 800 uA.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This high side switch using a PNP transistor acts like an "inverter circuit".

- Vin = 0V -> LED is ON
- Vin = 5V -> LED is OFF
  [image]

Adjust R3 to limit the current you want in the diode. Adjust R1 to have the the right saturation current flowing from emitter to base.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight!
As a follow up question, is there any way to achieve the same result but using an NPN transistor?
Many thanks!

Comment: @iAndrea If your VIN can handle the compliance current needed, you can just use 0 transistors. Just place a resistor in series with the diode, tie one end to +5 V and then tie the other end to VIN. Assuming you got the LED polarity correct, then when VIN is 0 the LED will be on. When VIN is +5 the LED will be off. That's it. But it requires VIN to be able to sink the LED current. I don't think you specified where VIN comes from. Or did I miss that? The other arrangement would be to use the NPN as a shunt, if you must use an NPN.

Comment: periblepsis the idea is I am trying to build an XOR gate that lights an LED on when the conditions are right (i.e. 1 0 or 0 1). That is why I am insisting on NPN transistors. I started with the inverter just to test the circuit conditions and later transfer the ideas onto the XOR gate.